# Do we have "issues"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

On [the tour page](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/about), under "**Get answers to practical, detailed questions**" it recommends that we "Ask about..." "Specific *issues* with Computer Science education." There are "issues" with CS education, but this site is about many other parts of CS education as well. It'd be really nice to rephrase it to something more accurate like:

> Specific questions about teaching Computer Science or about Computer Science education.

Comment: I kind of see where you are going, but what are the "many other parts of CS education" that we are leaving out? I feel like "issues with CS education" is all-encompassing enough to cover what you wrote.

Comment: Saying "issues" sounds awkward to me.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. "Issues" has an odd connotation in our context. I see the reason for your edit now. Even "topics in" would be better. Maybe edit your question to put "issues" in quotes to call our attention more directly to that diction?

Comment: I vote *yes*, but are we even able to do this?

Comment: Issue means “to come out of”, but a lot of people see it to mean “problem/defect”.

Comment: @richard "Specific coming out ofs with CS Ed"? I don't see how the other difinition of issue helps here.

Comment: I am saying that “Specific issues with Computer Science education.” means approximately “Specific things from Computer Science education” or “Specificly from Computer Science education”. But a lot of people will read it as “Specific problems with Computer Science education”. (Because, due to its general usage being low among most people, and its prevalence in the field of defect management,  the word issue has come to be associated with defects/problems).

Comment: @richard Euphemism Creep - words come to take on the connotation of how people actually use them. Toilet originally meant 'grooming'. Handicap originally meant "a disadvantage placed on a better player to make the contest equal." Very gentlemanly. Urr, person-ly. So, with the word issue, the coming forth of the negative association that you described.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why “issues” would be inappropriate or misleading in this context. We do have issues. What we don't have is *an issue with computer science education*. I do agree that “issues with + noun” is weird here. I propose “specific issues related to computer science education” or “specific issues with teaching computer science”.

Moderators can change this text.

Comment: I really like the former formulation: “specific issues related to computer science education”.

Comment: "*Specific things that are, well, not really* problems, *you know, or negative or that would be like, looking down on someone or something, but which, you know, we want to... uh, do something about. Capiche?*"

Comment: "*To take arms against a sea of Troubles, and by opposing, end them.*"

Comment: "*Nothing new is learned until existing systems have failed to maintain equilibrium.*" (Piaget, yeah, the education theorist guy)